# Por que o CodeIgniter entende uma rota como diretório e quebra os links?

Tags: codeigniter, controller, rotas

Montei um sistema em CI que utiliza o esquema de template, com header, navmenu, template (componente) e footer.

Para estilização utilizo o Foundation.

O problema é o seguinte: ao acessar uma rota simples, como por exemplo a home, não tenho erros, mas ao acessar uma rota como user/new a página perde a referência, pois os links para o css, js e imagens, que estão com link relativo, ficam apontando para um subdiretório de user/ pois o sistema pensa que está dentro deste diretório, mas o mesmo não existe, é apenas um controller.

Isto não acontece com os métodos padrão (index) dos controllers, apenas quando tento acessar outro método através da combinação controller/metodo na url.

Alguém conhece esse erro e como corrigir?

Answer (score 0):

Está utilizando a helper url? Se sim, está também utilizando o base_url();
se não, o base_url ele gera todo o caminho do seu projeto, precisando apenas que você liste precisamente a pasta e o nome o arquivo que quer acessar.

E você retirou o index.php pelo htaccess?

Comment: Sim, o .htaccess está configurado.
Eu fiz um teste com o base_url() e ele corrige, mas o que não entendo é por que o sitema entende a rota como diretório.